# Почему игру "Инди кот" упорно пишут без дефиса?

Tags: орфография, приложение

Чем Индиана кот лучше (хуже) Москвы-реки?

Comment: Я как-то попросил присылать мне на почту красивые имена котов. Один прислал: Дивуар.

Comment: *Один прислал: Дивуар.* - Эта шутка старше самого Дивуара, который страна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Индиана Кот (Инди Кот)](http://branto.ru/index/igra_indi_kot_i_klubok_sudby_podskazki_pravila/0-1891) — легендарный путешественник, который отправился на поиски старинного артефакта предков.

Это составное имя  собственное (состоит из двух равнозначных имен), оба слова пишутся с прописной буквы.

Москва-река, Казбек-гора, полынь-трава — дефисное написание родовых наименований в функции приложения, стоящего после определяемого слова.

Comment: *Это составное имя собственное (состоит из двух равнозначных имен)* Все ничего, но с чего бы кот (именно кот - рыжий, хитрющий, только сказочный) стало именем собственным?

Comment: К тому же - ссылка у вас - на спин.

Comment: Серый Волк - тоже составное имя собственное, оба слова пишутся с прописной буквы.

Comment: Серый Волк - не составное имя. Оно неделимо. Как Красная Шапочка. В составном второе слово писалось бы со строчной. О том и речь.  Кстати, здесь это было бы правильнее, писать кот со строчной. По образцу колхоза "Запах революции".

Comment: Сиби, спасибо! Мне что-то такое мерещилось, что должно быть какое-нито рациональное объяснение. "Составное имя собственное", принято!

Comment: Его приравняли к Индиане Джонсу или к Коту в сапогах. Можно было "Индианский кот" (в оригинале Инди - прилагательное; при написании без дефиса нужно добавлять русское окончание), "кот из Индианы" или "кот Инди".

Comment: С дефисом же прочтение наводит на мысль о созвучном русском обзывательстве.

Answer (score 1):

Москва-река вызвана к жизни необходимостью отличать от омонима. Другими словами, Москва-река - это имя собственное. В "Инди кот" второе слово как часть собственного имени пока не воспринимается. Впрочем, не знаю, что там фаны этого кота себе думают, я к таковым себя не отношу.

Кстати, посмотрел. Они этого Кота вообще с заглавной пишут. Т.е. все "с точностью до наоборот". Но в любом случае - не приложение.